# Parallax background-image in wrapper not responsive

Tags: css, html, responsive-design, background-image, parallax

I made a website using an HTML5 template and adjusting it. Everything worked fine so far (apart from probably having messy files).

Now, my issue:

I am using a parallax background image inside a section-element, and it is not responsive on mobile. If I resize my browser window, it works fine. But if I look at the actual size on my smartphone screen, it's not working.

This is the code I used in my CSS-file. I tried to do it with code that I found in this community and merged it with what was already inside the template.

```
.wrapper.rechtsgebiete {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
    padding: 10em 0 6em 0 ;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flex;
    display: flex;
    -moz-align-items: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    -moz-justify-content: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    -ms-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-color: rgba(51,153,255, 0.80);
    background-image: url(../../images/la-rechtsgebiete.jpg);
    background-position: top left;
    background-size: cover;
    border: none;
    min-height: 50vh !important;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
        }
```

This is the HTML-element:

```
    <section id="rechtsgebiete" class="wrapper rechtsgebiete" style="padding-top: 30vh; padding-bottom: 25vh;">
    <div class="inner"><center>
    <h1 class="font-volkhov2"><span style="color:white;">Services & Rechtsgebiete</span></h1></center>
    </div>
    </section>
```

Here you can see the issue; the first header-image works fine, everything else doesn't: http://lexadvice.de/leistungen.html

How can I solve this issue?
I tried changing the position value, but I guess it might have something to do with the width-property. Trial and error did not get me far this time.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue with setting the background on scroll. Now the images are displaying correctly on iPhone.

```
    background-attachment: scroll;
```

Thanks for your help @Akash Shrivastava.

Answer (score 0):

One of the media style rules is overriding the `background-attachment: fixed;` in file:    leistungen-banner.css

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1280px)
    #banner {
        padding: 6em 0 3em 0;
        background-attachment: scroll;
     }
}
```

that's why its not working on mobile. Please fix that.

Alternatively you can add and inline rule `background-attachment:fixed` to your #banner element.

Refer below screenshot (taken from chrome dev tools):

[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you for your fast answer. I used the inline method and it looks different now on mobile, but still not right. What is making the image so big on mobile? I'll try to get a screenshot.

Comment: Hi, so now I changed it on the Leistungen-Page. 2 images are displaying right, the other ones aren't. Why could that be?